# Using .NET Core Session in middleware

Tags: session, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

When I write middleware in .NET Core which short-circuits the chain and returns a response, it does not set the session cookie. A short example:

```cs
public class Middleware
{

    private RequestDelegate _next;

    public Middleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var req = context.Request;
        if (req.Path.ToString() == "/hello-world")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world!");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);

    }

}
```

Here is the relevant code from my `Startup` class:

```cs
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddDistributedMemoryCache()
            .AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app
            .UseSession()
            .UseMiddleware<Middleware>();
    }
}
```

Response headers on pass-through:

```
HTTP 200 No Error

Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8C1XpX5nCrFCnHz%2BDwlF41YjVSyPMqB8Qmk6qcDPnOSpG22yun3hsXpRBgMDhlX%2ByLbqkUtqPRYY%2B1%2Bno5WeRLnabM1zBDggvB4YEg6ooBiGN%2B5ktjjgfp4uH5mmlWZpEQyQJQb0vKDGwqWpMlLEGjMxVIMqOnkqjM0DvsQIPjt6; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Date: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 20:48:55 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers on the short-circuit:

```
HTTP 200 No Error

Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Date: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 21:17:39 GMT
```

In short, I need to know why the session middleware is not sending the cookie back. I also appear to get some session warnings when I load the page about not being able to decode the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hadn't added anything to the session so the middleware wasn't creating the session. Simply add `context.Session.SetString("stuff", "3");` (or one of Set* variants) in order to have the session sent to the client. You'll want to do this before you write to the response body.

Comment: thanx, helped me out. i was getting an error saying session not started despite adding/configuring as specified in .net core documentation. soon as I added a random variable, it worked! ;-)